# Wordpress: Can I use add_filter to change data for apply_filter that is inside a class?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, filter

So I have a Wordpress plugin with a section of code that sets the subject line of an email. This is in a function inside a class as below:

```
class FES_Vendor {

....

public function change_status( $new_status = '', $in_admin = false, $output = false ) {

....

$subject = apply_filters( 'fes_application_approved_message_subj', __( 'Application Approved', 'edd_fes' ), 0 );
```

The above sets the subject of the email to 'Application Approved'.
In my functions.php I've added the following in the hope of changing this to 'Welcome'.

```
function my_welcome_subject($subject) {
 $subject = __( 'Welcome', 'edd_fes' );
 return $subject;
  }
add_filter('fes_application_approved_message_subj', 'my_welcome_subject');
```

This makes no different. I've played around with the priority, tried negatives and extremely high values but still not effective.

So my question is, do I need to consider that the apply_filters is in a CLASS and if so how do I code?

(I'm not that familiar with CLASSES)

Comment: You don't need a class, the code with a function should work. have you checked that the `add_filter` is realy called before the e-mail is sent ?

Comment: @mmm thanks for the response. I'm not sure how to check the timing of each call, is there is way to see?

Comment: Add a line to echo to the debug file so you can see the timing and if the code is being executed.  You can write to the debug file with the following command "error_log( 'This is a debug message');"  You can read up on it here https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/using-the-wordpress-debug-log

Comment: @AndrewSchultz THANK YOU! This was good advice, I've not used the debugger before but it helped me track down that the original filter hook is the wrong one! I've since found the right one and it's now working. Good man, thanks again.

Comment: Always develop with debug on that's my number one rule :)